# Take a parameter and run a function based on that parameter

Tags: python

What is a move efficient way to run a function dependant on a parameter.
I will always know what x will be so I could store all these possibilities in a list but then how would this help me call the appropriate function?

Just for context, I have just over 12 possibility's for x and I get the feeling writing 12 if statements is just wrong.

```
def run(x):
    if x == "dog":
        dogfunction()
    if x == "cat":
        catfunction()
```

Comment: Your example will not work at all. = (single equal sign is an assignment, not equality check. You want == there.

Comment: Sorry I just quickly typed something to get an example of code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
def run(x):
    functions = {
        "dog": dogfunction,
        "cat": catfunction,
    }
    functions[x]()
```

This explicitly maps a string to a function. It also raises a `KeyError` in case the string isn't in the dictionary of functions.

Comment: It is advised to store that `functions` dictionary outside of the function btw., so it doesn’t need to be recreated with every call.